# Laravel and Vue.js filter table of users based on role

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I want to know if I can use Vue to filter my table of users based on their role.

I already have the methods on the controller done, and the blade template as well, however I want to show the filtered table instantaneously. Can this be done?

I thought of passing the contents of the table as props to the component and keep doing the HTTP request on the blade file, but I'm unsure if that's possible.

Comment: Yes! you can do this. you can send all of your data to front , and then filter that data by vue.

Comment: @AliSafaei Inside the table there are some buttons that are all based on blade, if I try to pass the table to the Vue component will I have to change all of those buttons? Or is there a way to just modify the table and keep the button untouched?